# printing the memory location and value pointed to by a pointer

Tags: c++

this is my code:

```
int myInt = 15;
int *myPointer;
myPointer = &myInt;
```

how do i get the memory location of myInt and value pointed to by myPointer? would i use the dereference operator?

Comment: @StephanLechner Please do not answer in comments.

Answer (score 2):

Memory location of `myInt` can be accessed with the `&` operator (in this context, called the "reference operator"), and once you assign it to a pointer, you can also print out the pointer's value.

The value pointed to by `myPointer` can be dereferenced with the `*` operator (in this context, the "dereference operator"), and once you assign `myInt`'s address to the pointer, its value is the value pointed to by `myPointer`.

Code snippet:

```
#include <iostream>

int main() {
    int myInt = 15;
    int *myPointer;
    myPointer = &myInt;

    std::cout << "Memory location of myInt: " << &myInt << std::endl;
    std::cout << "Value of myPointer: " << myPointer << std::endl;
    std::cout << "Value of myInt: " << myInt  << std::endl;
    std::cout << "Value pointed to by myPointer: " << *myPointer << std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
Memory location of myInt: 0x7ffe724fa57c
Value of myPointer: 0x7ffe724fa57c
Value of myInt: 15
Value pointed to by myPointer: 15
```

Answer (score 1):

> how do i get the memory location of myInt [...]?

```
std::cout << &myInt << '\n';
```

or

```
std::cout << myPointer << '\n'; // becase myPointer points to myInt, so its value is exactly &myInt
```

> [...] and value pointed to by myPointer?

```
std::cout << *myPointer << '\n';
```

Notice the `*` before `myPointer`. It's called *dereferencing*.

Answer (score 1):

Note that, in general, you might rather `cout << static_cast<const void*>(my_pointer)` to print its address.  If you try to print the address of a `char*`, you’ll find that `<<` is overloaded.

Another option is `printf( "%p\n", my_pointer );` from `<stdio.h>`.

Comment: In this example, the explicit cast to `const void*` is not necessary: `cout << my_pointer`.  ALL pointers are implicitly convertible to `void*`.  The only time you need to cast a pointer for `operator<<` is when you are dealing with a `char*` pointer, which has special meaning to `operator<<`.

Comment: @RemyLebeau In this example, it works, but it might not for all kinds of pointers—or if some other piece of code overloads `ostream::operator<<`. So, in the general case, such as writing a `template`, you might want to cast for safety.